# How to learn relation between field description and possible categories

Tags: tensorflow

I have a relation between products that looks like this

[image]

Is [*seq2seq*](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) a correct approach so my model can learn the relation between the text in both product (left column) and category (right column), and then being able to predict future categories given a product description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Seq2Seq` essentially have two different recurrent neural networks tied together : an encoder RNN that takes input `text tokens` and an decoder RNN that starts generating `text tokens` based on the outputs from the encoder RNN. Its a sequence to a sequence network. But your case as i see it, the inputs are a sequence and the output is a category based on the inputs. You better try an `LSTM` network which takes your input sequence through an `embedding layer` and then passing the last `hidden state` of the `LSTM` to a `dense layer` to make the classification.

An LSTM model for your use case:

## Placeholders for input and output

```
# input batch of text sequences of length `seq_length`
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, seq_length], name='input')

# Output class labels 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name='labels')
```

## Embedding layer

```
# For every word in your vocab you need a embedding vector. 
# The below weights are not trainable as we will `init` with `pre-trained` embeddings. If you dont want to do that set it to True.
W = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size]), name='embed', trainable=False)

# Get the embedding representation of the inputs
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, X)
```

## LSTM layer

```
# Create basic LSTMCell, with number of hidden units as a input param
def lstm_cell():
  return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden) 

# Create a stack of LSTM cells (if you need)
stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(n_layers)])

# Create a dynamic RNN to handle the sequence of inputs
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)

# get the output of the last hidden state
last_hidden = output[:, -1, :]
```

## Final dense layer

```
# output dimension should be `n_classes`.
logits = dense_layer(last_hidden ...)
```

This should be your Model.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Not sure what you mean by _"the output is a category based on the inputs"_. I have all the categories (outputs) already defined, I would like the network to learn the relation between input description and the category (output) text.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Read it has  `each outputs belongs to one category that you have defined and not a sequence`.

Comment: Ok, so I should try [a dense layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense). Will look for examples and find out how to use the categories text in that layer to help the network making the right prediction. Thank you! I will investigate/study and come back.

Comment: Could you give me a example of _"and then passing the last hidden state of the LSTM to a dense layer"_? I have been reading about your suggestion and not sure where to add the dense layer and how to connect the output of the LSTM to the dense layer...

Comment: I dont have a web site. New to SO, couldnt find a place where to add my email but twitter contact is displayed i guess.

Comment: is it ok to post skype id here?